# Multiple parameters in seed lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am utilizing the Seed() method to populate my database. I am trying to pre-populate one table with data based on two keys, not just one.

For example, I am doing this elsewhere and it is working fine:

```
foreach (var drug in Drugs)
{
    context.Drugs.AddOrUpdate(
        d => d.OrderId,
        drug
    );
}
```

Is it possible to do something like the following?

```
foreach (var pd in PatientDrugs)
{
    context.PatientDrugs.AddOrUpdate(
        (p => p.DispenseDate && p => p.DrugId),
        pd
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
foreach (var pd in PatientDrugs)
{
    context.PatientDrugs
        .AddOrUpdate(p => new { p.DispenseDate, p.DrugId }, pd);
}
```